# Building a chat app which can be plugged into any webapp

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, chat, chatbot

I have angularJs application which has a chat window for a chatbot, this chatbot has lot of css and directives used. Now my requirement is develop a chatbot which can be plugged into any webapp. If I want to reuse the existing chat window code to build independent pluggable chatbot. How can I do that? Should I have to create new angularJs application with all those css, directives, controllers and services? If I should do that how can I create a pluggable script which can be included any webapp. Can I include this new angulaJs chatapp into another angularjs webapp?

Comment: you would have 2 separate scripts, for css and js code (plus additional scripts like angular.js itself). It's best if the _chatbot_ is a directive/component that can be inserted with one line of code. Then you would need to initialise the angular module with your directive as a sub-module: `angular.module('app', ['chatbot'])`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works if the application i want to keep my chatbot is built with angularjs. I already have chatbot built inside my angularjs application with directive as you mentioned. But the problem now i want to solve is, i want to make this chat as a independent angularjs application which can be plugged into any application angularjs/react/jsp/simple html and js. Is it possible?

Comment: not unless you initialise angular.js with `ng-app` and `angular.module()` somewhere

Comment: sorry i didnt get that. you mean underneath angularjs application(the application first i built chatbot inside) or the chatbot angularjs application i wanted to build. I have underneath application already declared with ng-app and angular.module(). And now if i want to have ng-app and angular.module() for chat app also. Can i do that two ng-apps